# Draw multiple circles filled with image content

Tags: html5-canvas

I am trying to draw circles on a canvas filled with portions from an image. Imagine clicking on a white canvas and where the user clicked reveal a portion of a photo.

I have found ways to draw 1 circle, but can not succeed using this to draw multiples. If I repeat the action with other coordinates the drawing is not happening.

```
function start_drawing(){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,255)";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);//fill the background. color is default black
    ctx.arc(mouse.x,mouse.y,45,0,6.28,false);//draw the circle
    ctx.arc(mouse.x+100,mouse.y+100,45,0,6.28,false);
    ctx.clip();//call the clip method so the next render is clipped in last path
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0); 
    ctx.closePath();
}
```

Any idea on how this can be achieved ? 
Thank you.

---

### Later Edit (The entire exact code used)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script>

window.onload=function(){  

var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');  
var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');  

var mouse={x:0,y:0} //make an object to hold mouse position

canvas.onmousemove=function(e){mouse={x:e.pageX-this.offsetLeft,y:e.pageY-this.offsetTop};} //update the mouse when the canvas is moved over

var img=new Image();

img.src="bmw_gina.jpg";

setInterval( start_drawing ,100);// set the animation into motion

 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,255)";
 ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);//fill the background. color is default black
  ctx.closePath();

function start_drawing(){
 //ctx.save();
 ctx.beginPath();

                     ctx.arc(mouse.x,mouse.y,45,0,6.28,false);//draw the circle
                     ctx.clip();//call the clip method so the next render is clipped in last path
                     ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);  
 ctx.closePath();
 //ctx.restore();
}

}

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1003" height="914"></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you create a copy of this page, with all included code, on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Hi. I tried, but placing my code there and clicking run has no result at all, unlike the server where I do get 1 circle drawn. Here is the link with the code though http://jsfiddle.net/qCg9N/3/  . If you can help with anything, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues I can see with yor code:

The first is that `start_drawing` is clearing the canvas every execution. So for each mouse click (I assume that `start_drawing` is called on mouse click) the circle is drawn but the canvas is cleared before that.

the other is that You need to call `BeginPath` and `closePath` for each clipping region you want to create. so your code should look something like that:

```
function start_drawing(){ 

    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,255)"; 
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);//fill the background. color is default black
    ctx.beginPath(); 
    ctx.arc(mouse.x,mouse.y,45,0,6.28,false);//draw the circle
    ctx.clip();//call the clip method so the next render is clipped in last path 
    ctx.closePath(); 
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0); 
    ctx.beginPath(); 
    ctx.arc(mouse.x+100,mouse.y+100,45,0,6.28,false);
    ctx.clip();//call the clip method so the next render is clipped in last path 
    ctx.closePath();  
    ctx.drawImage(img2,0,0); 

}
```

### Update

Well apparently, the trick to reset the clipping region is to reset the canvas. This can be achieved by re setting it's width.

There you go:  http://jsfiddle.net/qCg9N/5/

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the help. I tried to place my entire code here http://jsfiddle.net/qCg9N/3/  . Here it doesn't render any circle, but at least you can take a look at the complete code. I changed it a little bit. What I think it should do: first draw white rectangle. Than on each mousemove call start_drawing function to draw the round region of the picture where the mouse is. But somehow only the first circle is drawn. Any idea ? Thank you.