# How to draw only a circular part of an image with HTML 5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

How can I draw only a circular part of an image using HTML 5 canvas?

For instance, to take a photo and only draw the face inside the canvas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way to achieve this is to use `clip` to define a clipping region:

```
var ctx;
var canvas;

var img = new Image();

img.onload = function() {

    canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(100, 100, 60, 0, 6.28, false); //draw the circle
    ctx.clip(); //call the clip method so the next render is clipped in last path
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.drawImage(img, -190, 0);
};

img.src = "http://www.antiquiet.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/Free-Trapper_Remasters_The-Kills-467x311.jpg";
```

You can see a working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/hJS5B/47/

Code reused from my answer to this question: [Draw multiple circles filled with image content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634620/draw-multiple-circles-filled-with-image-content/5647854#5647854)

Comment: antiquiet.com doesn't seem to allow hotlinking - in order for this to work, you have to copy the image URL to your browsers address bar an load it so the image is in your browsers cache (you won't have that problem with an image loaded from your own server).

Comment: Scratch that, it's not hotlink protection, it's because you didn't draw the image in an onload handler, so it wouldn't work with an image not already cached. I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

As I found this thread long before I found the solution for what I was searching for: the code above works great. But if you want to draw circular areas of an image again and again, e.g. in an onmouseup event, then you have to save and restore the state of the context. More is explained here: [Can you have multiple clipping regions in an HTML Canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551411/can-you-have-multiple-clipping-regions-in-an-html-canvas)